# Exporting a Spring Boot Project as a JAR with dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot project that I would like to use as a dependency in another project.

First, in my pom.xml, I set the **packaging** tag to jar. However, that produced a jar with a BOOT-INF folder, which could not be imported inside the other project. In order to fix that, I added the following lines:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Now, when I run `mvn clean package` two jars are generated:

1. A jar that can correctly be imported, but lacks the the depedencies
2. Another jar with the `BOOT-INF\lib` folder (containing the dependencies)

I would like to make it so the first jar also contains the libraries.

Comment: Is my answer solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in pom.xml and try again.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Note - There is no need to add a class with the main method, so you can remove a similar class like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```